# Python - split string without inner string

Tags: python, string, split

I wanted to ask. if there is an efficient way to split a string and ignore inner strings of is

Example:
I get a string in this format:

```
s = 'name,12345,Hello,\"12,34,56\",World'
```

and the output I want, is:

```
['name', '12345', 'Hello', "12,34,56", 'World']
```

by splitting at the "," the numbers become separated:

```
['name', '12345', 'Hello', '"12', '34', '56"', 'World']
```

I know I could split at \" and split the first and the third part separately, but this seems kind of inefficient to me

Comment: Actually, this was the string I wanted to mention...
s = 'name,12345,Hello,\\"12,34,56\\",World'

big Sorry for that!

I edited it above

Answer (score 3):

This job belongs to the `csv` module:

```py
import csv

out = next(csv.reader([s], skipinitialspace=True))
# out is
# ['name', '12345', 'Hello', '12,34,56', 'World']
```

**Notes**

- The `csv` library deals with comma-separated values, perfect for this job
- It understands quotes, which your input calls for
- The `csv.reader` takes in a sequence of texts (i.e. lines of text)
- The `skipinitialspace` flag is just that: it tells the reader to skip initial spaces before each value

Answer (score 2):

If your string separates each element with a comma and a space you could pass `", "` to your `split` method like this:

```py
>>> s = 'name, 12345, Hello, \"12,34,56\", World'
>>> print(s.split(", "))
['name', '12345', 'Hello', '"12,34,56"', 'World']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try built-in `csv` module to parse the string:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO

s = 'name, 12345, Hello, "12,34,56", World'

print(next(csv.reader(StringIO(s), skipinitialspace=True)))
```

Prints:

```
['name', '12345', 'Hello', '12,34,56', 'World']
```